# ANTLR: Different token with trailing bracket

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, flex-lexer, lex

I am working on an ANTLRv4 grammar for [BUGS](https://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/software/bugs) - my repo is [here](https://github.com/talesa/bugs2foppl/tree/318450cbd5df54a226ff850468215c53d9775374), the link points to a particular commit so shouldn't go out of date.

Minimum code example below.

I would like the input rule to go along `t` route if input is `T(`, but to go along the `id` route if the input is `T` for the grammar below.

```
grammar temp;

input: t | id;
t: T '(';
id: ID;

T: 'T' {_input.LA(1)==(}?;

ID: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._]*;
```

My ANLTRv4 specification of BUGS grammar was obtained heavily inspired with the FLEX+BISON lexing and parsing grammar incorporated in [JAGS](http://mcmc-jags.sourceforge.net/) 4.3.0 [source code](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/JAGS/4.x/Source/), in files `src/lib/compiler/parser.yy` and `src/lib/compiler/scanner.ll`.

The way they accomplish it is by using the trailing context in the lexer, e.g. `r/s`. The way to do it in ANTLR is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535089/flex-r-s-in-antlv4), but I cannot get it to work.

I need it to work this way because another part of the grammar depends on this mechanism - relevant code fragment [here](https://github.com/talesa/bugs2foppl/blob/318450cbd5df54a226ff850468215c53d9775374/bugs.g4#L17-L32).

You can recreate my particular issue by cloning [my repo](https://github.com/talesa/bugs2foppl/tree/318450cbd5df54a226ff850468215c53d9775374) and running `make` - this will give list of tokens lexed and error in parsing stage. In the tokens list the letter `T` is lexed as token `'T'` rather than `ID` as I'd like it to be.

I feel there is much more natural/correct way to do it in ANTLR, but I'm new to this and cannot figure out a way.

PS If you have an idea how to better name this question please edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly the following code will work fine:

```
grammar temp;

input: t | id;
t:     T '(';
id:    ID | T;

T:      'T';
LPAREN: '(';
ID: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._]*;
```